# How to skip json object if it has a empty value?

Tags: php, json, api, if-statement, foreach

I'm stuck on this since many days... I'm using this code to parse a json EPG guide stored on a server:

```
<?php
$channel = '899';
$current_unix = time();
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://guidatv.sky.it/app/guidatv/contenuti/data/grid/'.date('y_m_d').'/ch_'.$channel.'.js', true));
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($json->plan as $prog) {
echo "<li>" . $prog->title . "</li>";
echo '</ul>';  
}
?>
```

I would like to skip this part of the json from showing because it has empty fields

```
"banned":true,
"plan":[
{"id":"-1",
"pid":"0",
"starttime":"00:00",
"dur":"65",
"title":"",
"normalizedtitle": "",
"desc":"",
"genre":"",
"subgenre":"",
"prima":false 
},
```

How can I do that?

Comment: based on which empty element basically you want to skip? title, desc, or any-one else?

Comment: I want to skip empty title

Comment: @YvesLeBorg What about `$plan->title = ""` ? that will pass the condition

Comment: Get used to good habits. do `echo "<li>" . htmlspecialchars($prog->title) . "</li>";` instead of `echo "<li>" . $prog->title . "</li>";` . to protect yourself from HTML injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add in your foreach a condition like:

```
foreach ($json->plan as $prog) {
    if(empty($json->plan->title)) continue;
    echo "<li>" . $prog->title . "</li>";
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Be careful with the "0" problem, if the title is "0" it will not be echoed. also remove the `</ul>` from the loop

Comment: it works but the first entry has a strange indentation that I can't remove: http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/i765-2ajn

Comment: As Accountant said, </ul> must be outside, I updated my answer, check it out